# Using different Events in single input field with angularjs, typeahead and angular-validators

Tags: angularjs, validation, bootstrap-typeahead, input-field, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using an input field which has several extentions. 
The input field contains a validation called generalValidation. ng-model-options="{updateaOn:'submit'}" is set because the validation has to be evaluated when the form is submitted. if there exists a better implementation,  please let me know.
The next step is to implement a typeahead functionality. This is done with the uib-typeahead. The purposes of the typeahead functionality should change after any key is pressed. But the purposes appear when the submit button is pressed. That's because of the updateaOn:'submit' property. Is there any way to customize this situation? Can I maybe modify, manipulate or extend the typeahead or the validation with custom events. Is there a common way with angular to fix this problem?
Here is the complete Codde of the input field:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
            <div ng-class="{'has-error':reverInputForm.reverProducerName.$invalid && reverInputForm.$submitted}">
                <input name="reverProducerName"
                       uib-typeahead="Cooling for Coolin in vm.loadCoolingEntities($viewValue)"
                       type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Kühlung eingeben"
                       generalvalidations   
                       ng-model="vm.ReverType.ReverProducer.Name"
                       ng-model-options="{updateOn:'submit'}" />
                <div ng-messages="reverInputForm.reverProducerName.$error"
                     ng-show="reverInputForm.$submitted"
                     style="padding:0.2% 0% 0.4% 0%">
                    <div class="label-danger small validationErrorBlock">
                        <div ng-messages-include="validation-error-messages" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The validation is implemented with the $validators of angular:

```
 generalValidations.prototype.link = function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl)
        {
            ngModelCtrl.$validators.notEmpty = function (modelValue, viewValue)
            {
                if (viewValue == '' || viewValue == null)
                    return false;
                return true;
            };
        };
```

Many Thanks!!!